# Installing httplib2 through the Python console in QGIS 2.18.0 on Windows OS

Tags: python, qgis-2.18

I want to install [httplib2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/httplib2/wikis/Install.wiki) through the Python console in QGIS 2.18.0 on Windows OS, in order to use another plug-in [instagram2qgis](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/instagram2qgis/). 
I downloaded and unzipped the folder of httplib2 but I don't know how to install it.

Comment: [@Federico Godino](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127314/federico-godino) have you seen this topic: [Python: Httplib2 Module Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882465/python-httplib2-module-not-found)?